# Entity Framework No corresponding Column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, api, stored-procedures

I have been battling this issue for a while, I fix it from on one machine, merge to GIT and pull on another (with identical databases) and the error arises again. I can't figure it out for this particular case.

I have a stored procedure that returns the following:

[image]

When I run my code and hit this endpoint I get an error:

> The data reader is incompatible with the specified *my complex type here*. A member of the type 'CUSTOMER_ID' does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.

I don't get why it doesn't work, I have other procedure that are very similar, and all work fine. My complex type is set up as `ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON_Result` and is a scalar int32 named `CUSTOMER_ID`. The functional import for my `ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON` stored procedure is set to that complex type.

My model's context CS for this stored procedure is

```
public virtual ObjectResult<ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON_Result> ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON(Nullable<int> cOMPANY_ID, string cUSTOMER_NAME, string fIRST_NAME, string lAST_NAME, string aDDRESS_1, string aDDRESS_2, Nullable<int> cITY_ID, Nullable<int> sTATE_ID, Nullable<int> zIP_CODE_ID, string pRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER, string aLTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBER, string sECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER, string eMAIL_ADDRESS, string cUSTOMER_NOTES, string mODIFIED_BY, ObjectParameter cUSTOMER_ID)
{
    var cOMPANY_IDParameter = cOMPANY_ID.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("COMPANY_ID", cOMPANY_ID) :
                new ObjectParameter("COMPANY_ID", typeof(int));
    
    var cUSTOMER_NAMEParameter = cUSTOMER_NAME != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("CUSTOMER_NAME", cUSTOMER_NAME) :
                new ObjectParameter("CUSTOMER_NAME", typeof(string));
    
    var fIRST_NAMEParameter = fIRST_NAME != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("FIRST_NAME", fIRST_NAME) :
                new ObjectParameter("FIRST_NAME", typeof(string));
    
    var lAST_NAMEParameter = lAST_NAME != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("LAST_NAME", lAST_NAME) :
                new ObjectParameter("LAST_NAME", typeof(string));
    
    var aDDRESS_1Parameter = aDDRESS_1 != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("ADDRESS_1", aDDRESS_1) :
                new ObjectParameter("ADDRESS_1", typeof(string));
    
    var aDDRESS_2Parameter = aDDRESS_2 != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("ADDRESS_2", aDDRESS_2) :
                new ObjectParameter("ADDRESS_2", typeof(string));
    
    var cITY_IDParameter = cITY_ID.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("CITY_ID", cITY_ID) :
                new ObjectParameter("CITY_ID", typeof(int));
    
    var sTATE_IDParameter = sTATE_ID.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("STATE_ID", sTATE_ID) :
                new ObjectParameter("STATE_ID", typeof(int));
    
    var zIP_CODE_IDParameter = zIP_CODE_ID.HasValue ?
                new ObjectParameter("ZIP_CODE_ID", zIP_CODE_ID) :
                new ObjectParameter("ZIP_CODE_ID", typeof(int));
    
    var pRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBERParameter = pRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("PRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER", pRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER) :
                new ObjectParameter("PRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER", typeof(string));
    
    var aLTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBERParameter = aLTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBER != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("ALTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBER", aLTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBER) :
                new ObjectParameter("ALTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBER", typeof(string));
    
    var sECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBERParameter = sECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("SECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER", sECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER) :
                new ObjectParameter("SECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER", typeof(string));
    
    var eMAIL_ADDRESSParameter = eMAIL_ADDRESS != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("EMAIL_ADDRESS", eMAIL_ADDRESS) :
                new ObjectParameter("EMAIL_ADDRESS", typeof(string));
    
    var cUSTOMER_NOTESParameter = cUSTOMER_NOTES != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("CUSTOMER_NOTES", cUSTOMER_NOTES) :
                new ObjectParameter("CUSTOMER_NOTES", typeof(string));
    
    var mODIFIED_BYParameter = mODIFIED_BY != null ?
                new ObjectParameter("MODIFIED_BY", mODIFIED_BY) :
                new ObjectParameter("MODIFIED_BY", typeof(string));
    
    return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON_Result>("ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON", cOMPANY_IDParameter, cUSTOMER_NAMEParameter, fIRST_NAMEParameter, lAST_NAMEParameter, aDDRESS_1Parameter, aDDRESS_2Parameter, cITY_IDParameter, sTATE_IDParameter, zIP_CODE_IDParameter, pRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBERParameter, aLTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBERParameter, sECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBERParameter, eMAIL_ADDRESSParameter, cUSTOMER_NOTESParameter, mODIFIED_BYParameter, cUSTOMER_ID);
}
```

I make the call to this stored procedure in my controller here:

```
[HttpPost, Authorize]
public ObjectResult<ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON_Result> CreateCustomer([FromBody]dynamic customerInput)
{
    var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
    var claimRole = identity.Claims.ToList()[0].Value.ToInt();
    var claimCompany = identity.Claims.ToList()[3].Value.ToInt();
    var claimUsername = identity.Claims.ToList()[5].Value.ToString();
    int[] allowedRoles = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 , 8};

    if (Array.IndexOf(allowedRoles, claimRole) != -1)
    {
        if (claimRole == 3 && claimCompany != customerInput["companyID"].ToString().ToInt())
        {
             throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
        }

        var companyID = (int)customerInput["COMPANY_ID"];
        var customerName = customerInput["CUSTOMER_NAME"].ToString();
        var firstName = customerInput["FIRST_NAME"].ToString();
        var lastName = customerInput["LAST_NAME"].ToString();
        var address_1 = customerInput["ADDRESS_1"].ToString();
        var address_2 = customerInput["ADDRESS_2"].ToString();
        var cityID = (int)customerInput["CITY_ID"];
        var stateID = (int)customerInput["STATE_ID"];
        var zipID = (int)customerInput["ZIP_CODE_ID"];
        var primaryPhoneNumber = customerInput["PRIMARY_PHONE_NUMBER"].ToString();
        var alternatePhoneNumber = customerInput["ALTERNATE_PHONE_NUMBER"].ToString();
        var secondaryPhoneNumber = customerInput["SECONDARY_PHONE_NUMBER"].ToString();
        var emailAddress = customerInput["EMAIL_ADDRESS"].ToString();
        var customerNotes = customerInput["CUSTOMER_NOTES"].ToString();
        var modifiedBy = claimUsername;

        ObjectParameter output = new ObjectParameter("cUSTOMER_ID", typeof(int));
        var test =  database.ADD_CUSTOMER_JSON(companyID, customerName, firstName, lastName, address_1, address_2, cityID, stateID, zipID, primaryPhoneNumber, alternatePhoneNumber, secondaryPhoneNumber, emailAddress, customerNotes, modifiedBy, output);
        return test;
    }

    throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized));
}
```

I am not super great with EF but I haven't had this many problems with any other SP so I am just getting sort of frustrated.

I just don't get why it says I don't have a corresponding column when there is a column set as output being returned with the name it should be expecting. The actual complex type model looks normal as well, it only has one property and it is the int named `CUSTOMER_ID`. If I change my controller function to return an int, and change the functional import to none it will work but always return -1, if I change the functional import to scalar and then int32 it complains again about missing columns.

Let me know where I can clarify anything. Also I have tried changing the SP to not have the return Value and only return the @CUSTOMER_ID however, that doesn't change anything.

***EDIT***
Also, another strange phenomenon that I can't answer is that when I add most stored procedures to entity, if they have a return it will automatically make a complex type and reference it with the functional import. This particular one does not, when I "update" my stored procedures and add this one it makes the functional import but has it set to none and I had to manually create the complex type. I thought it was interesting but my knowledge of entity lacks a bit in that area and so I do not understand fully why that happens the way it does.

Answer (score 0):

I changed SP to remove both `@CUSTOMER_ID` and `Return Value` and ran a query to return `CUSTOMER_ID` and that seems to have worked with some minor tweaking of the controller output.